# Athena cannot query against Glue-crawled tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I used Glue Crawler to create a table on top of a folder with Snappy Parquet file in S3. Queries fail with "SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1.8 Column 'isfraud' cannot be resolved."

Yet when I replicate that exact table manually, the same query succeeds. I tried this with a crawler on the same underlying S3 path, and also by using  crawler on a copy of the  same data to another path without special characters like dashes. See image.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` seems to confirm that automatically generated and manually generated schemas are the same. See below.

The same thing happens with CSV-formatted data.

Adding single-quote, double-quote, or backtick around the table name in the query (either with the database name or separately) does not make a difference; nor does adding the Database name to the query.

How can I query a generated table?

[image]

- The manually  defined  table where the query  succeeds.

  `SHOW CREATE TABLE mdforaugmentedparquet.snappyparquet1;`

  ```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `mdforaugmentedparquet.snappyparquet1`(
      `isfraud` int, 
      `step` int, 
      `hourof24` double, 
      `hourof24_nml` double, 
      `type` string, 
      `type_cash_out` int, 
      `type_transfer` int, 
      `amount` double, 
      `amount_nml` double, 
      `nameorig` string, 
      `oldbalanceorg` double, 
      `oldbalanceorg_nml` double, 
      `oldbalanceorigsign` int, 
      `newbalanceorig` double, 
      `newbalanceorig_nml` double, 
      `negdeltaorigin` double, 
      `negdeltaorigin_nml` double, 
      `namedest` string, 
      `oldbalancedest` double, 
      `oldbalancedest_nml` double, 
      `expectednewbaldest` double, 
      `expectednewbaldest_nml` double, 
      `newbalancedest` double, 
      `newbalancedest_nml` double, 
      `isflaggedfraud` int)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
      's3://sagemaker-819/augmented-parquet/'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
      'classification'='parquet')
  ```
- An automatically crawled table where the query  fails.

  `SHOW CREATE TABLE mdforaugmentedparquet.augparquetsnappy;`

  ```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `mdforaugmentedparquet.augparquetsnappy`(
  `isfraud` int, 
  `step` int, 
  `hourof24` double, 
  `hourof24_nml` double, 
  `type` string, 
  `type_cash_out` int, 
  `type_transfer` int, 
  `amount` double, 
  `amount_nml` double, 
  `nameorig` string, 
  `oldbalanceorg` double, 
  `oldbalanceorg_nml` double, 
  `oldbalanceorigsign` int, 
  `newbalanceorig` double, 
  `newbalanceorig_nml` double, 
  `negdeltaorigin` double, 
  `negdeltaorigin_nml` double, 
  `namedest` string, 
  `oldbalancedest` double, 
  `oldbalancedest_nml` double, 
  `expectednewbaldest` double, 
  `expectednewbaldest_nml` double, 
  `newbalancedest` double, 
  `newbalancedest_nml` double, 
  `isflaggedfraud` int)
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
  OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
  LOCATION
  's3://sagemaker-819/augparquetsnappy/'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='augmentedparquetsnappy', 
  'averageRecordSize'='125', 
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'objectCount'='1', 
  'recordCount'='2811841', 
  'sizeKey'='260257084', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
  ```
- Another automatically crawled table where the query also fails.

  `SHOW CREATE TABLE mdforaugmentedparquet.augmented_parquet;`

  ```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `mdforaugmentedparquet.augmented_parquet`(
  `isfraud` int, 
  `step` int, 
  `hourof24` double, 
  `hourof24_nml` double, 
  `type` string, 
  `type_cash_out` int, 
  `type_transfer` int, 
  `amount` double, 
  `amount_nml` double, 
  `nameorig` string, 
  `oldbalanceorg` double, 
  `oldbalanceorg_nml` double, 
  `oldbalanceorigsign` int, 
  `newbalanceorig` double, 
  `newbalanceorig_nml` double, 
  `negdeltaorigin` double, 
  `negdeltaorigin_nml` double, 
  `namedest` string, 
  `oldbalancedest` double, 
  `oldbalancedest_nml` double, 
  `expectednewbaldest` double, 
  `expectednewbaldest_nml` double, 
  `newbalancedest` double, 
  `newbalancedest_nml` double, 
  `isflaggedfraud` int)
  PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `partition_0` string)
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
  OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
  LOCATION
  's3://sagemaker-819/augmented-parquet/'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='augmentedparquet', 
  'averageRecordSize'='125', 
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'objectCount'='1', 
  'recordCount'='2811841', 
  'sizeKey'='260257084', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
  ```
- Here is the description of autogenerated `augparquetsnappy` table (where queries fail).

  ```
   DESCRIBE FORMATTED `mdforaugmentedparquet.augparquetsnappy` 


    # col_name              data_type               comment             

    isfraud                 int                                         
    step                    int                                         
    hourof24                double                                      
    hourof24_nml            double                                      
    type                    string                                      
    type_cash_out           int                                         
    type_transfer           int                                         
    amount                  double                                      
    amount_nml              double                                      
    nameorig                string                                      
    oldbalanceorg           double                                      
    oldbalanceorg_nml       double                                      
    oldbalanceorigsign      int                                         
    newbalanceorig          double                                      
    newbalanceorig_nml      double                                      
    negdeltaorigin          double                                      
    negdeltaorigin_nml      double                                      
    namedest                string                                      
    oldbalancedest          double                                      
    oldbalancedest_nml      double                                      
    expectednewbaldest      double                                      
    expectednewbaldest_nml  double                                      
    newbalancedest          double                                      
    newbalancedest_nml      double                                      
    isflaggedfraud          int                                         

    # Detailed Table Information         
    Database:               mdforaugmentedparquet    
    Owner:                  owner                    
    CreateTime:             Tue Nov 17 10:55:56 UTC 2020     
    LastAccessTime:         Tue Nov 17 10:55:55 UTC 2020     
    Protect Mode:           None                     
    Retention:              0                        
    Location:               s3://sagemaker-819/augparquetsnappy  
    Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE           
    Table Parameters:        
      CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion  1.0                 
      CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion    1.0                 
      UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER    augmentedparquetsnappy
      averageRecordSize     125                 
      classification        parquet             
      compressionType       none                
      objectCount           1                   
      recordCount           2811841             
      sizeKey               260257084           
      typeOfData            file                

    # Storage Information        
    SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe  
    InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat    
    OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat   
    Compressed:             No                       
    Num Buckets:            -1                       
    Bucket Columns:         []                       
    Sort Columns:           []                       
    Storage Desc Params:         
      serialization.format  1
  ```
- I further created a copy of   `augparquetsnappy` table, by running the `CREATE` command above. Queries *succeed* on this copy, `augparquetsnappy2`. Here is  the description of that table.

  ```
        DESCRIBE FORMATTED `mdforaugmentedparquet.augparquetsnappy2` 


        # col_name              data_type               comment             

        isfraud                 int                                         
        step                    int                                         
        hourof24                double                                      
        hourof24_nml            double                                      
        type                    string                                      
        type_cash_out           int                                         
        type_transfer           int                                         
        amount                  double                                      
        amount_nml              double                                      
        nameorig                string                                      
        oldbalanceorg           double                                      
        oldbalanceorg_nml       double                                      
        oldbalanceorigsign      int                                         
        newbalanceorig          double                                      
        newbalanceorig_nml      double                                      
        negdeltaorigin          double                                      
        negdeltaorigin_nml      double                                      
        namedest                string                                      
        oldbalancedest          double                                      
        oldbalancedest_nml      double                                      
        expectednewbaldest      double                                      
        expectednewbaldest_nml  double                                      
        newbalancedest          double                                      
        newbalancedest_nml      double                                      
        isflaggedfraud          int                                         

        # Detailed Table Information         
        Database:               mdforaugmentedparquet    
        Owner:                  hadoop                   
        CreateTime:             Thu Nov 19 18:31:47 UTC 2020     
        LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN                  
        Protect Mode:           None                     
        Retention:              0                        
        Location:               s3://sagemaker-819/augmented-parquet     
        Table Type:             EXTERNAL_TABLE           
        Table Parameters:        
            CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion    1.0                 
            CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion  1.0                 
            EXTERNAL                TRUE                
            UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER      augmentedparquetsnappy
            averageRecordSize       125                 
            classification          parquet             
            compressionType         none                
            objectCount             1                   
            recordCount             2811841             
            sizeKey                 260257084           
            transient_lastDdlTime   1605810707          
            typeOfData              file                

        # Storage Information        
        SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe  
        InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat    
        OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat   
        Compressed:             No                       
        Num Buckets:            -1                       
        Bucket Columns:         []                       
        Sort Columns:           []                       
        Storage Desc Params:         
            serialization.format    1
  ```

Comment: Could you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE mdforaugmentedparquet.augparquetsnappy` and  `SHOW CREATE TABLE mdforaugmentedparquet.snappyparquet1` and post the result?

Comment: Done. I actually created 2 automatically-crawled tables, one with a partition key to see if that makes a difference; and one of those 2 is on the same underlying S3 data, and the other is on a copy of that data with no special characters like - in the path

Comment: @PhilippJohannis I diffed those outputs, and there seems to be no real difference,

Comment: did you run the query including the schema like `select * from mdforaugmentedparquet.augparquetsnappy`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Indeed, I tried it with the schema and without, and with all combinations of ' " ` , wrapping each component of the database and table name or the whole thing.  We get the same results, or other errors indicating bad syntax

Comment: The last table is defined as partitioned table but linking to the same bucket as the first non-partitioned table. That's not really possible as the underlying data is either partitioned or it's not.

Comment: Thank you. I  do see that one is partitioned ---  this came from the crawler. Yet this cannot be the distinguishing factor, since the manually-defined table allows queries, and the automatically crawled table on the identical copy of the single snappy file also does not allow queries, with the same error message

Comment: Did you try to manually recreate the table with the automated generated statement and a different table name. Maybe it's a permission issue of the crawler that creates the table.

Comment: Thank you. The manually recreated copy of augparquetsnappy allows queries. But what does that tell us? How could query failure be a permission issue of the crawler that creates the table? The table was created correctly by the crawler, and the error occurs only at query-time.

Comment: Can you update your question with output of DESCRIBE FORMATTED <table> for both tables ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Thank you. I added the `DESCRIBE` output (search for `DESCRIBE FORMATTED` above) for a nonfunctioning table and its functioning copy. Diff shows that the nonfunctioning table has owner "owner" and the functioning table has owner  "hadoop". Also the functioning table has  "EXTERNAL TRUE" on it. Are these differences meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the user executing the statement doesn't have permission to get the table metadata from glue as the table was created by Glue Crawler.

Glue permissions can be assigned on different, levels, catalog, database and table. If the user executing the select statement doesn't have permission explicitly on all tables or implicitly on all tables by giving permission on the database, you won't be able to query certain tables, see also [IAM actions available in Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awsglue.html#awsglue-actions-as-permissions).

This might be helpful as well, [Attach a Policy to IAM Users That Access AWS Glue](http://Attach%20a%20Policy%20to%20IAM%20Users%20That%20Access%20AWS%20Glue)

Comment: Thank you. The user here is just me. I am able to see metadata for all tables in the GUI, and to retrieve this metadata with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. So what permission would be missing?

Comment: It still seems like everything relevant is identical at query-time, even though at table-creation time, things are different.

Comment: Looking at LakeFormation, all permissions are created at the database level, not the table level -- so it seems that that would not differ

Comment: Yes, the user is just you, but Glue Crawler has it's own role and therefore the roles (and permissions) might differ. It's hard to say which permission is missing. I guess you could look into https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home and just ensure that your user has full access on Glue

Comment: OK, I gave my user EVERY built-in Role with the word Glue in it (except 2 with DataBrew in the name). This did not change the error resulting from the query.

Comment: Hmm, since you can access the S3 file the only other permission are athena permissions itself. I mean the only difference between the crawler creating the table and you doing it manually is the role that is executing the statement.

Comment: @PhillippJohannis Thank you. I added  descriptions (search for `DESCRIBE FORMATTED` above) for a nonfunctioning table and its functioning copy. Diff shows that the nonfunctioning table has owner "owner" and the functioning table has owner  "hadoop". (Also the functioning table has "EXTERNAL TRUE on it.) What might this mean? The owner names here seem nonintuitive, and it is not clear what relation they would have to querying permissions.